# Console Kafka Consumer does not receive any value from Producer?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Going through this website i created Kafka Producer and Kafka Consumer

https://www.tutorialkart.com/apache-kafka/kafka-console-producer-and-consumer-example/

but my consumer is not taking any value from my producer , so i decided to accept through Spring-boot but the same case consumer is not taking the producer's value.

I have gone through few post in StackOverFlow but none of them solved my problem.

here is my code in Spring.

Application.java

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
        ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory,
        KafkaTemplate<Object, Object> template) {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    configurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory);
    factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(
            new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(template), 3)); // dead-letter after 3 tries
    return factory;
}
```

and Consumer.java

```
@KafkaListener(id = "com.stellapps.rtcreset.kafka.consumer", topics = "${rawEventsTopicName}") // add it in   config part
public void messageListener(String in) {
    System.out.println("Received from message: " + in);
    rtcInterpreter.call(in,url);
}
```

can anyone help??

Comment: Are you able to do the steps 3 to 5 from the quickstart: https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart ?

Comment: any update on quickstart steps?

Comment: show the consumer properties

Comment: sorry for the delay. yes i was able to complete step 3 to 5 in quick start, i think the problem lies in the producer..

Comment: @Deadpool i do not have one i'am using the default one provided by spring boot